# Make Bluetooth on Android 2.1 discoverable indefinitely

Tags: android, bluetooth

I'm working on a research project which involves Bluetooth and the Android OS. I need to make Bluetooth discoverable indefinitely in order for the project to continue.

*The Problem:*

- Android limits discoverability to 300 seconds.
- I cannot ask the user every 300 seconds to turn discoverability back on as my application is designed to run in the background without disturbing the user.
- *As far as I am aware*, there is no way to increase the time though Android's GUI. Some sources have called this a safety feature, others have called this a bug. There may be a bit of truth in both...

*What I'm Trying / Have Tried:*

- I'm trying to edit a stable release of [cyanogenmod](http://www.cyanogenmod.com) to turn the discoverability timer off (it's possible; there's a configuration file that needs to have a single number changed). This isn't working because I'm having verification problems with the resulting package.
- During the past week, I downloaded the [cyanogenmod source code](http://github.com/CyanogenMod), changed a relevant class in the hope that it would make Bluetooth discoverable indefinitely, and tried to [recompile.](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.com/index.php/Compile_for_dream) This did not work because (a) the repo is frequently changed, leading to an unstable code base which fails to compile (OR, it could be that I'm using it incorrectly; just because it looked like it was the code's fault in many instances doesn't mean I should blame it for all the problems I encountered!) and (b) the repo decides to periodically "ignore" me (but **not** always, as I have gotten the code base before!), replying to my synchronization/connection attempts with:

  > fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

As you might imagine, the above two issues are problematic and very frustrating to deal with.
*More Info:*

- I'm running Android 2.1 via cyanogenmod (v5 I believe). This means the phone is also rooted.
- I have a developer phone, which means that the bootloader is unlocked.
- My phone is an HTC Magic (32B).

*The Big Question:*

- How can I make Bluetooth indefinitely discoverable on Android?

Comment: If you have the source, you could use some private api to turn bluetooth discoverable directly every 300 seconds. However I don't really know if it is possible and how to do this.

Comment: I can actually change a few values in the source code and (theoretically) turn off the 300 second timer altogether. Unfortunately, I'm having a multitude of problems compiling which is why I'm looking for an alternative here. However, if I can get it to compile and my first idea fails, then that is a very reasonable solution. I'll keep it in mind, thank you!

Comment: But by turning off the 300 second timer do you mean that users would need your custom rom?

Comment: Since this a research project, we (myself and the other researchers) are distributing our own phones, each of which will have the custom rom.

Comment: Oh, then I think that would be the best option.

Comment: I'm asking this on other forums as well; if I get a response that works, I'll post it here.

Comment: Deat Kanov , Discoverable (make own device discoverable for other) and Do Discovery for other devices both are different things. . .the link you posted related to make own device discoverable for other devices for unlimted time . .these days I am also searching regarding these both solutions -:)P

Comment: @Kanov-baekonfat, have u got the solution till now?

Comment: @Aftab, same question for u, as in above comment?

Answer (score 8):

See the following link:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/wireless/bluetooth.html#ConnectingDevices

Specifically, the last sentence in the paragraph below:

> **Enabling discoverability**
>   If you would like to make the local device discoverable to other devices, call `startActivityForResult(Intent, int)` with the `ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE` action Intent. This will issue a request to enable discoverable mode through the system settings (without stopping your application). By default, the device will become discoverable for 120 seconds. You can define a different duration by adding the `EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION` Intent extra. The maximum duration an app can set is 3600 seconds, and a value of 0 means the device is always discoverable.

So, this should work:

```
Intent discoverableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
discoverableIntent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION, 0);
startActivity(discoverableIntent);
```

Comment: This was not available in Android 2.1. It was available at least since Android 4, so on newer devices, yes, this is a solution.

Comment: The docs say it was added in `android-5`, so it should be 2.0 and above: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html#EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION

Comment: it will still give the user dialog confirmation, @gymshoe.... not the solutions i guess

Answer (score 0):

If you check out [the BluetoothAdapter class](http://hi-android.info/src/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.java.html)

you will find the hidden method:

```
public void setDiscoverableTimeout(int timeout)
```

Now you only have to find out how to use it. You have to do a method invocation to do so.

Comment: BTW how can you use, it is not recognizable dear

Comment: In many version of Android this method restricts discoverability to a few minutes.

Comment: "BTW how can you use, it is not recognizable dear"
what do you mean by "not recognizable" ??
this method is definitely held by this class.
it is marked as @hide.
you can invoke hidden methods...

here is an example
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462968/how-to-unpair-bluetooth-device-using-android-2-1-sdk/6181809#6181809