# How to get information about CONNECTED bluetooth device for android?

Tags: bluetooth, headset

If I have a Android phone which is already connected with a bluetooth headset (paired and connected) to it.
How I can get information about that specific headset.

Using `getBondedDevices()` method I get list of all paired devices..I need information about CONNECTED device only.

I can not wait for broadcast receiver to check status, because I need this information at the start of my application. So please suggest is there any way to get this information without waiting for broadcast.

Comment: See my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14991158/using-the-android-recognizerintent-with-a-bluetooth-headset/14993590#14993590

Answer (score 0):

You can do this through the IBluetoothA2dp interface in API 11 and up.  Some more info on there is here: [Android connect to a paired bluetooth headset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6161870/android-connect-to-a-paired-bluetooth-headset/8814016#8814016)

Here is a great resource to see the difference in what is available to this interface between API 10 and 11 where it changed quite a bit.
http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/bluetooth/BluetoothA2dp.java/?v=diff&id2=2.2_r1.1

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [getConnectedDevices](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothProfile.html#getConnectedDevices%28%29) for the HEADSET Profile to get the device to which it is connected.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out to see if headset is connected (ICS only):

```
    public boolean isVoiceConnected()
    {
        boolean retval = true;
        try {
            retval = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().getProfileConnectionState(android.bluetooth.BluetoothProfile.HEADSET) != android.bluetooth.BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED;

        } catch (Exception exc) {
            // nothing to do
        }
        return retval;
    }
```