# How can I avoid or dismiss Android's Bluetooth pairing notification when I am doing programmatic pairing?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I have an app where I am programmatically controlling Bluetooth pairing and unpairing.  I can pair before connection and unpair afterwards.  The reason I need to do this is specific to my application and not in the scope of my question.

Basically what I am doing is:

1. Get a reference `ib` to `IBluetooth` object as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462968/how-to-unpair-bluetooth-device-using-android-2-1-sdk)
2. Register a BroadcastReceiver for `android.bluetooth.device.action.PAIRING_REQUEST`
3. Call `ib.createBond(address)`
4. Wait for BroadcastReceiver to trigger
5. Convert user pin into bytes with [convertPinToBytes()](http://www.google.com/codesearch#uX1GffpyOZk/core/java/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.java&q=convertPinToBytes&type=cs)
6. Call `ib.setPin(address, pinBytes)` from within BroadcastReceiver

Anyways, this approach works great, except for the fact that when I do the pairing, I get a notification in the Status bar requesting that the user enter a PIN to complete the pairing.  But this is in fact unnecessary, because by the time the user sees this, my app has already used `setPin()`.  I'd really like for that notification to either a) not appear at all, or b) be dismissed automatically somehow.

I realize this may not even be possible, but I thought I would ask in case someone has a creative idea.

Comment: Can you please add some sample code (or a link to your source code).
What I want to do is actually the same as you. I want to connect to a device without the password request. Kind regards, Jeroen

Comment: I can't share my source code unfortunately, but the step-by-step that I have above is very close to the actual code.  You can get started with the source code in the answer I link to in Step 1.

Comment: @JoelF have you solved your problem? Because I'm not. Really appreciate if you can share how you solve, if that's the case.

Comment: Sorry, I changed jobs and don't work on this anymore.  We ended up just living with the pop-up on the first connection and not unpairing afterwards.  Subsequent connections do not give the pop-up because the pairing is now in place.

Comment: this still works in 4.2.1? Cause they worked on BT and changed things lately..

Comment: @Ewoks Sorry, this was last tested on 2.3.  I never tried anything later.

Comment: seems like Google changed something in Bluez starting with 4.1 ..

Answer (score 20):

Try setting the confirmation first in the `PAIRING_REQUEST`

```
BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra("android.bluetooth.device.extra.DEVICE");

device.getClass().getMethod("setPairingConfirmation", boolean.class).invoke(device, true);
device.getClass().getMethod("cancelPairingUserInput").invoke(device);
```

This worked for me between two Android devices using RFCOMM but I'm not entering any PINs

Comment: As a side note, calling cancelPairingUserInput has not been necessary in my tests.

Comment: This does not work. If i use this code the pairing process does not start and i get an error message that there is no such method called 'cancelPairingUserInput'

Comment: I just noticed that this also works to prevent annoying pairing request pop-ups when connecting to already paired devices on certain models running recent versions of Android (GT-I9295, Android 4.4.2)

Answer (score 14):

Since Android API 19 Google switched these Methods to public Methods, so there is no need for Reflection any more. :)

Answer (score 1):

Do this in the PAIRING_REQUEST notification event:

```
BluetoothDevice localBluetoothDevice = (BluetoothDevice)intent.getParcelableExtra("android.bluetooth.device.extra.DEVICE");

Class localClass = localBluetoothDevice.getClass();
Class[] arrayOfClass = new Class[0];
localClass.getMethod("cancelPairingUserInput", arrayOfClass).invoke(paramBluetoothDevice, null)).booleanValue();
```

But you gotta tell me how did you pair your remote device without the user to enter Passkey/PIN? off course, you know the PIN for the remote device which is trying to pair to your device but how did you provide that PIN to the remote device.

Comment: Interesting, let me give that a try.  I've updated my answer to be a little more specific about how I did the programmatic pairing without user interaction.  Hope that helps.

Comment: Can you explain what is the paramBluetoothDevice exactly?