# Connecting to a specific bluetooth port on a bluetooth device using Android

Tags: android, mobile, bluetooth, communication

Is there any way for Android to connect to a Bluetooth device using a specific port instead of using service UUID? 
I know this option is available in other platforms which provide Bluetooth support (Java ME for example by specifying a "btspp://" style URL).

Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

Ok, it's been a while, but I found a solution to the problem. I actually intended to give up and use UUID, but I kept getting a Service Discovery Failed (IO)exception, and when I tried to find a solution to the service discovery issue, I found the solution to my original question... Ain't life something?:)

Anyways, [this is the link I stumbled upon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397071/service-discovery-failed-exception-using-bluetooth-on-android), though you should note there is a mistake in the answer (they actually simply connected to port 1, instead of using a service UUID).

And after this short history lesson, here is the solution:

Using reflection, it is possible to create the Rfcomm socket connecting to a port number instead of UUID:

```
int bt_port_to_connect = 5; // just an example, could be any port number you wish
BluetoothDevice device = ... ; // get the bluetooth device (e.g., using bt discovery)
BluetoothSocket deviceSocket = null;
...
// IMPORTANT: we create a reference to the 'createInsecureRfcommSocket' method
// and not(!) to the 'createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord' (which is what the 
// android SDK documentation publishes
Method m = device.getClass().getMethod("createInsecureRfcommSocket", new Class[] {int.class});

deviceSocket = (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(device,bt_port_to_connect);
```

A few things to notice:

1. since we're using Invoke, the first parameter is the object we're invoking the method on, the second parameter of invoke is actually the first function parameter)
2. There is also a secure version available ('createRfcommSocket'), which accepts a bluetooth channel number as a single parameter (again, since this is invoke style, you'll need to pass the object to invoke the method on, as mentioned in -1- )
3. I found what appears to be [a link to these functions' prototypes](http://hi-android.info/src/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.java.html)

Good luck to all.

Answer (score 0):

Bluetooth Android connections are exclusively done via UUID. Each Bluetooth device has a UUID for every service it runs (see Bluetooth SDP).

You just give Android the UUID to watch for and, in client mode, it will find a socket to connect to automatically (including port). In server mode, it will wait for the specified device to initiate a connection using the specified UUID.
The BluetoothSocket object is also valid when connection is established (use getInput/Output Stream)
See  [Server Socket documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothServerSocket.html) and [Client Socket documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothSocket.html).

---

If you really want to check everything, you can see what Android decodes from the other device's SDP and the UUID you provided.

Use [this tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462968/how-to-unpair-bluetooth-device-using-android-2-1-sdk) to get the Bluetooth interface (very easy to do).
Then the code should look something like this:

```
IBluetooth ib =getIBluetooth();
Int otherDevicePort = ib.getRemoteServiceChannel(otherDeviceAddress, UUID);
```

Comment: Thanks! I actually found a solution to the problem (now as an answer below). When I tried to use UUID, I kept getting an IOException of Service Discovery Failed, but I'll check your suggestion and see if this solves the exception..

Comment: I don't know about this....I mean sure it fixes your problem, but, how on earth do you know the other device's port without SDP? Do you just assume it is always 1 (because yo do nothing else with the other device on Bluetooth?)

Comment: My problem was indeed uncommon and very specific, since I need to communicate with a custom device, which is always listening on a specific port and doesn't expose a service record UUID. You're right that in most cases, the standard (and probably the recommended) way is to use SDP to find a service record the device exposes and find the port based on that record.

Comment: @radu I'm trying to connect the Android app to a Linux computer. Unfortunately the Python bluetooth API connects via port number instead of a UUID. In older versions of the Android BluetoothDevice API, it used to allow RFCOMMs connection to a port number as well. However, in current Kotlin versions, that's been phased out.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [bluecove](http://bluecove.org/) which allow me to do so with the function `Connector.open()`.

I use the following url:
`btspp://" + phoneID + ":" + phonePort`

N.b.: Some options can be added (e.g.: `authenticate=false;` or `encrypt=false;`).

With `phoneID` being the the being the Bluetooth address and `phonePort` the port number.

**How to find the Bluetooth address?**
From this [link](https://www.technipages.com/android-find-bluetooth-address):

> 1. From the Home screen, open the app drawer, then open “Settings“.
> 2. Select “System“. (Skip this step on some models)
> 3. Scroll down to the bottom and tap “About Phone“, “About device“, or “About tablet“.
> 4. Scroll down to the bottom and tap “Status“.
> 5. Scroll down and the “Bluetooth address” will be shown in the list.

**How to find the port number?**
I haven't been able to find which port is supposed to be used yet... 
I used 5 and it works but I need to research why and if I want to change the phone I will need to know if I also need to change the port.