# Discovering all Bluetooth devices UUID around (iOS, Android)

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-device-discovery

First, please pardon me if the question is close to some topics of other threads. I searched previous topics but as I'm not a programmer/technician, I could not be sure they answered my question exactly.

In fact, I'm wondering whether it is possible to develop an application on iOS or Android that would scan for Bluetooth devices around (in particular, other Smartphones with Bluetooth enabled) and gather all their UUIDs.

- Is there a constraint (such as a preliminary pairing) required?
- Could the other devices have their screen locked / off, as long as Bluetooth is enabled? After some basic tests just trying to discover an iPhone device from my Windows Phone (from the user interface, not programmatically), I realize that the iPhone disappears from the Windows Phone list as soon as its screen turns off; still, it is recognized in my car (with which it is paired) even though its screen is off.
- Are there constraints relative to the Bluetooth version? I read on this website that iOS does only discover Bluetooth 4.0 devices.

In summary, I need an app that would run on iOS and Android and which would be able to scan for all other mobile phones with Bluetooth enabled and gather their UUID, irrespective of their current status (idle, screen off, ..).

Thank you in advance.

Best

Comment: Yes it's possible. Kind of weird that you were able to find the device  in one way but not another when the screen was off though. Also, it's not unusual to disable stuff like that when the screen turns off.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What about the Bluetooth version? May I identify a mobile with Bluetooth 4.0 (such as an iPhone 5) with an older phone running Bluetooth 3.0? What about the reciprocal situation?

Comment: For inst. I found this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3190623/make-bluetooth-on-android-2-1-discoverable-indefinitely?rq=1 where it seems that an Android device may only be discovered during a limited period of time. Is it actually the case?