# Bluetooth discovery without prompt in Android

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am able to turn on/off Bluetooth without any prompt using the following code. It requires `BLUETOOTH` and `BLUETOOTH_ADMIN` permissions.

```
boolean isEnabled = bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled();
if (enable && !isEnabled) {
    return bluetoothAdapter.enable();
} else if (!enable && isEnabled) {
    return bluetoothAdapter.disable();
}
```

But didn't find any way to set Bluetooth discoverable without user prompt. It's wired to prompt every time to user. There is no "don't ask me again" feature I afraid. Is there any good way to make Bluetooth device discoverable? I don't care about the duration. Also my device is not rooted.

## More Info

I found source code of [BluetoothAdapter.java](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.2_r1/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.java#BluetoothAdapter) and it has a public method named `setDiscoverableDuration`. But why I can't access it? Why some public methods are hidden in Api documentations? How did they even do that? all methods are public.

Comment: Not sure if i understand you correctly, but discoverable applies to the remote device, it must be discoverable in able to find it with a scan.

Comment: @JPS Using discoverable I mean that my device should be found by other device when they will scan.

Comment: Checkout this, seems to be hidden: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3190623/make-bluetooth-on-android-2-1-discoverable-indefinitely

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Finally I have found a way to do this using reflection.

```
Method method;
try {
    method = bluetoothAdapter.getClass().getMethod("setScanMode", int.class, int.class);
    method.invoke(bluetoothAdapter,BluetoothAdapter.SCAN_MODE_CONNECTABLE_DISCOVERABLE,120);
    Log.e("invoke","method invoke successfully");
}
catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**Warning: Above method is trying to invoke hidden method. So in future maybe it will not work.**

Comment: This works and should be accepted as the answer
 
EDIT: oops you're the OP

Comment: today by android 7 or 8 it's no longer working... any other clues?